# How make discord.ext.tasks send in channel by id every x minutes in cogs

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

i tried

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from discord.ext import commands
import discord
import random
import asyncio,json
from discord.ext.commands import clean_content
from datetime import datetime
import aiohttp
from discord.ext import tasks
class Test(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.test1.start()
    @tasks.loop(minutes=1.0)
    async def test1(self):
        channel=bot.get_channel(927612404056092702)
        channel.send(mensagem)
def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Test(bot))
```

using
`channel=self.bot.get_channel(927612404056092702)`
return AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
and using
`channel=bot.get_channel(927612404056092702)`
return NameError: name 'bot' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

`bot.get_channel` method retrives channel from cache. You can properly do it only after `on_ready` event:

```py
class Test(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @tasks.loop(minutes=1.0)
    async def test1(self):
        channel=bot.get_channel(927612404056092702)
        channel.send(mensagem)

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        if not self.test1.is_running():
            self.test1.start()


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Test(bot))
```